# Zurb Ink Inliner converting HTML special characters

Tags: zurb-foundation, special-characters, html-email

I have been using the Ink Inliner over the past year and just recently noticed that all of my HTML special characters are being converted to plain text by the inliner? Is this intentional or do I need to add the characters back in each time after running through the inliner? Seems counter-intuitive for the inliner to strip them out unless this is intended for plain text emails.

Comment: can we see what your html looks like after the inliner?

Comment: e.g. &copy; is getting replaced with © and &rsquo; is replaced with '